# Escuchar eventos en contratos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy intentando escuchar eventos de errores y transacciones correctas, pero no logro hacerlo.

```
await contract.mint(mintAmount, {
    gasLimit: String(385000),
    value: totalCostWei,
  }).once("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    setFeedback(
      "Disculpe, algo salió mal, por favor pruebe de nuevo más tarde"
    );
    setClaimingNft(false);
  })
```

Me dice que once no es una funcion, quisiera escuchar los eventos cuando se produce un error y cuando la transaccion es recibida correctamente. Estoy usando Etherjs v5